# Numpy lines intersects circles

Tags: python, numpy

I have n lines and m circles.

I have a [n,2] numpy array of line start points:

```
[x1_1,y1_1],
[x1_2,y1_2],
...
[x1_n,y1_n]
```

And a [n,2] numpy array of line end points:

```
[x2_1,y2_1],
[x2_2,y2_2],
...
[x2_n,y2_n]
```

And an [m,2] numpy array of circle centers:

```
[cx_1,cy_1],
...
[cx_m,cy_m]
```

And an [m,1] numpy array of circle radii:

```
[cr_1...cr_m]
```

I would like to efficiently get an [n,m] numpy array where array[i,j] is True if line i intersects circle j.

In general I would take the normalised perpendicular vector to each line and take the dot product of that with each (xi,yi) - (cx_j,cy_y) and ask if it's less than cr_i; but I also have to check whether that implied point is on the line and check each end individually if not.  I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Yeah, I cannot see a more efficient algorithm than your proposed one. Maybe just write it and validated it with `python`/`numpy` and then for speed use `numba` or `cython`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, assume to have these shape

```
start = (np.random.random((3,2))-.5)*5
end = (np.random.random((3,2))-.5)*5
center = (np.random.random((4,2))-.5)*5
radius = np.random.random((4,1))*3
```

[image: this is the case in exame]

for each center we can compute the distance from the three lines by:

```
D = np.array([
    np.linalg.norm(np.cross(end-start, start-c).reshape(-1,1),axis=1)/np.linalg.norm((end-start).reshape(-1,2), axis=1)
    for c in center
]).T
```

D[i,j] will be the distance between line i (in rows) and center j (in clumns).
Now we can simply compare this distances to the radius distances with:

```
I = (d<radius.repeat(len(start), axis=1).T)
```

I is a matrix of the same shape of D; I[i,j] is True if the distance between the line i and the center j is lower than the radius j (and so if the line i intersect the circle j) and False otherwise.

I know it is not very elegant, but I hope it can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a substantially simpler algorithm than the one outlined in the question. As far as the implementation is concerned, it is easy to make these computations using `shapely`.

First, lets generate and plot some sample data:

```
from itertools import product
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point, MultiLineString
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate data
rng = np.random.default_rng(123)
start = (rng.random((3, 2)) - .5) * 5
end = (rng.random((3, 2)) - .5) * 5
center = (rng.random((4, 2)) - .5) * 5
radius = rng.random((4, 1)) * 3

# plot lines and circles
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(8, 8)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

colors = list(mcolors.TABLEAU_COLORS.keys())
for i, ends in enumerate(zip(start, end)):
    ax.plot(*zip(*ends), label=f"line {i}")

for i, (c, r) in enumerate(zip(center, radius)):
    ax.add_patch(Circle(c, r, fill=False, ec=colors[i], label=f"circle {i}"))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image: lines and circles]

Next, compute the array of intersections, with rows corresponding to lines and columns corresponding to circles:

```
lines = [LineString(ends) for ends in list(zip(start, end))]
circles = [Point(c).buffer(r).boundary for c, r in zip(center, radius)]
out = np.empty((len(lines), len(circles)), dtype=bool)
for i, (l, c) in enumerate(product(lines, circles)):
    out[np.unravel_index(i, out.shape)] = l.intersects(c)

#convert to a dataframe for better display
df = pd.DataFrame(out)
df.index.name = 'lines'
df.columns.name = 'circles'
print(df)
```

The result:

```
circles      0      1      2      3
lines                              
0         True  False   True   True
1        False  False  False   True
2        False  False  False  False
```

Comment: "for i, (l, c) in enumerate(product(lines, circles)):
    out[np.unravel_index(i, out.shape)] = l.intersects(c)"
I'm looking for efficiency, so really looking for a series of calls on the whole set at once